# how to show background image(multiple) if out of current div

Tags: html, css

`container`div has two images, I make them display left and right:

```
 .container {
  background-image: url('img/left.png'),url('img/right.png');
  background-position: left,130px;
    overflow: visible;//this line doesn't work
  }
```

currently, right.png is out of the right boundary of the `container` div and is hidden behind another named div2 which is at the right side of the `container` div.

How to make right.png image display on top of div2?
see below structure:

[left.png------ 'I am container div'---------  ][right.png-----I am div2 -------]

for some reason, it is not possible to change the css of div2, so I am wondering if it is possible to set some attribute inside `container` div then right.png can show up.

see below I draw a picture: I set right.png 125px to show, ideally, it would cover the grey triangle.

1. Can not add padding to the `container`, can not change position of div2 (because there are other menus share this part, whole part of `container` div would turn grey if other menu was clicked.)

[image]

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: The clue is in the name: **back** ground-image. The background images will always be shown at the back of the parent element i.e. behind the child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is div2 positioned absolute? If so, you can only place .container higher by positioning it absolute as well and setting the z-index higher than div2, or by placing .container after div2 in the DOM.